# Plotly Figure. How to get the number of rows and cols?

Tags: python, plotly

I create a Plotly Figure instance this way:

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, row_width=[0.3, 0.3, 0.4])
```

Lets assume that now I do not know how many rows and cols the Figure instance has. How can I obtain these values? For example, I expect something like this:

```
rows = fig.get_rows_num()
cols = fig.get_cols_num()
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: This does not seem to give any information about the number of columns that can be obtained from the internal structure. If it is the number of graphs, we can get it this way, but.. `x=0;for keyword in fig.layout:
    if keyword.startswith('xaxis'):
        x += 1`

Comment: as @r-beginners mentioned, you can determine the number of subplots, but you cannot determine the number of rows or columns. You can look into `fig.full_figure_for_development()` but i didn't find any results. can i ask about your use case? in what situation will you not know how many rows and cols you have beforehand?

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I managed to implement what I need using the number of subplots only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same use case come up! I was happy to find you can do this:

```py
rows, cols = fig._get_subplot_rows_columns()
```

Comment: wow. not all heroes wear capes. thank you!